# Overflow hbox in paragraph when making tables using tabu

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabu

I am looking to create a table that spans the entire available column width (because there is too much text) using the following code.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,             % Use US letter-size paper
               oneside,                 % No verso and recto differences
               \pointsize]              % Uses the font size defined above
               {memoir}
               
\usepackage{calc}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}%          % Specifies \paperheight and \paperwidth
  {\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}                     % Set location of page in relation to the stock.

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h] % Table float
    \caption{Layers of Evidence-Centered Design}
    \label{table\arabic{tablecounter}}
    \begin{tabu}{@{}p{0.14\columnwidth}p{0.26\columnwidth}p{0.25\columnwidth}p{0.29\columnwidth}@{}} \\ \hline
    a & b & c & d\\ \hline
    a & b & c & d\\
    a & b & c & d\\ \hline
    \end{tabu}
    \legend{\emph{Source}: \textcite{mislevy2012design}}
    \end{table}
    \refstepcounter{tablecounter}
\end{document}
```

Table has four columns, all different width. Total width of table being `0.14 + 0.26 + 0.25+ 0.29`, i.e. 0.94

So table width is less than the available column width, even then latex is complaining about overfull hbox. How do I make sure that it used the available width, nothing more, nothing less, if total width is not 1*columnwidth (or textwidth; none works as expected).

Addiotionally, how do I make the table good. it looks ugly as there no space in some entries within a column. Due to this they seem to be partially overlapping as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

UPDATE: I used `\begin{tabu} {X[1,l]X[3.1,l]X[3.1,l]X[4,l]}` and enclosed the table within `\begin{landscape}` and `end` clause from `pdflscape` package. table looks a lot better now. However, I am still getting overflow error. How do I make sure not to overflow the hbox. I know there are a lot of posts regarding overflow hbox but still not able to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: `tabularx` may be more suited -- have alook at the answer below -- the `L` type `newcolumn` definition can be changed to `\centering in place of `\RaggedRight`  -- similarly the `extrarowheight` can be changed to choice

Comment: Avoid tabu, see the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: please don't edit answers into the question it makes it hard for later readers. Your original table was wider than the page (due to your specified widths of p columns not taking account of the \tabcolsep white space padding around each column) that is fixed using X columns, but the error shown in the added example is unrelated: it is a _vertical_ overflow as the table is too big to fit in a `table` float. `tabu` or `longtable` or derived environments can break over a page but not inside a `table` environment.  A floating `table` has to fit on the page.

Comment: your example generates the error `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \pointsize`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following based on `booktabs` and `tabularx` on a landscape oriented page. I also used the `\widthof` command from the `calc` package in order to determine an appropriate width for the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[h] % Table float
    \caption{Layers of Evidence-Centered Design}
    \label{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{Conceptual}}XXX@{}} 
    \toprule
    a & b & c & d\\ 
    \midrule
    Domain Analysis & \lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][2-4] & \lipsum[1][1-3]\\  \addlinespace
    Conceptual assessment framework & \lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][2-5] & \lipsum[1][1-3]\\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \legend{\emph{Source}: }
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

In the example code, columns 2 to 4 are of equal width. If you prefer different widths for these columns, you could alternatively use something like

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{Conceptual}}p{5cm} X p{4cm}@{}}
```

Comment: It does look good with this but the overflow hbox is not planning to go away even with this. should i worry about overflow hbox

Comment: @vipin8169: If I compile the example in my answer, I don't get any warnings. If I use the alternative for different column widths, I do get warnings, but they are "**Under**full \hbox"  warnings as opposed to "**Over**full \hbox"  warnings. (The underfull \hbos warnings are caused by the justified alignment in quite narrow columns. You could switch to a ragged right alignment to avoid these.) If you really get "Overfull \hbox"  warnings, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: sorry, my bad. i am getting uderful warnins, not overfull. 2 underfulls and another which says float too large for page. how do i fix those?

Comment: i am already using `raggedright` as indicated in the answer

Comment: In my answer, I only used a ragged right alignment for the first columns, while the other three remain justified. Depending on the column widths and contents of these columns, you might want to use ragged right for them as well in order to prevent the underfull box warnings.

Comment: Float too large for the page indicates that the table is too tall for the available space and thus protrudes into the bottom margin. To prevent this, either reduce the font size of the text in the table or switch to xltabular to allow a page break inside of the table.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.5\baselineskip}
    \caption{Layers of Evidence-Centered Design}

    \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
        
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llLL@{}}
            \toprule
            a & b & c & d\\ \midrule
            a & b & \lipsum[7] & \lipsum[7]\\
            a & b & \lipsum[7] & \lipsum[7]\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
﻿
```

Comment: it did not work. in fact it broke completely. see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eht59.png

Comment: how do i make sure that hbox does not overflow? settting width such that sum of four columns=1 does not work.